# Will windows server 2008 show PAE memory in task manager

Tags: windows-server-2008, pae

First off I am a programmer I am just investigating this and making sure I have my facts straight.

We are getting some memory issues on a terminal server when a few people load a program that uses quite a lot of memory (but not out of the ordinary). I looked in task manager and the memory shown is only 3325MB physical. I guess limited by the 4GB 32 bit limit.

However I know this server has 16GB of memory and should have PAE enabled. Would I expect to be able to see the full 16GB of memory in task manager if PAE were enabled? 
Or does the way PAE works mean it will still only show 4GB but actually use 16GB.

I want to make sure I have this correct before proceeding. This is a Windows Server 2008 32 bit terminal server, I hope they will move it to 64 bit anyway at some point.

Answer (score 1):

try rebooting after running (from an admin command prompt) `bcdedit /set pae forceenable`  Note that you will likely run out of free page table entries before you run out of ram.

Comment: Yeah I have found the command but should the memory show in task manager? It's just one of those flaws I can imagine being the case.

Comment: it depends on what service pack you are on: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929580/en-us